# discord-jda. Отправка embed в определенное время

Tags: java, quartz, discord-jda

Мне необходимо отправлять некую вставку на текстовой канал, например, каждое утро, как это возможно сделать?
Думал воспользоваться Quartz, но как мне кажется, что то подобное можно реализовать и при помощи одного лишь JDA

Answer (score 0):

Да, ты можешь использовать JDA или любой другой механизм взаимодействия с Discord API.

Тебе потребуется использовать Quartz библиотеку вместе с JDA в одном проекте, потому что каждая из них решает свою задачу.

- JDA позволит описать тебе механизм отправки рассылки.
- Quartz позволяет запускать твой код (отправку рассылки) по расписанию.

Удачи!